# asp.net 3.5. grid view - visible="false" controls not getting value when calling update statement

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, datagridview

in asp.net 3.5[vs2008] Gridview i got one issue.
i have binded objectdatasource with datagridview, provided Get and Update method in ojectdatasource . and in gridview i made some Bound fields visible ="false"[e.g. Primary Ke,Id, foregin Key fields which i need at time of update]. but when i did debugging, i am not getting values for fields which i made visible="false" in updatemethod.

i used 3-tier architecture and passing Businessobject from DAL to BAL to UI and UI to BAL to DAL.

so please can anyone suggest me that if i want some fields which are for coding puporse and should not be displayed to users. what is the method to do it in GridView?

Comment: string EmpId = grdview1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

Comment: Use DataKeyNames="urID" in your gridview

Comment: provide sample code of your gridview..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your primary key and foriegn key column names to the GridViews's DataKey property.

Comment: @least 1 datakey should we need to specify.

Comment: @solairaja can we have multiple datakeys for a gridview

Comment: and also Gridview has one propery called DataKeys (its a collection)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx

Comment: @ solairaja until now i thought that one can't use multiple datakeys in a gridview... You gave the way ...